# What to do if someone doesn't want to publish a result?

Tags: soft-question, math-communication, journals

Unfortunately, there are many unpublished results that should be published or at least made available online. For different reasons, the author might not want to publish it. The result can also fall into several categories, such as

1. People in the field know about the result and believe the proof is correct.
2. People in the field heard about the result but are not sure about the (exact) proof.
3. Practically nobody knows about the result.

My question is about type 3. What is the right way to make people know about the result?

In my case, in a class I had a student who came up with a proof for a well-known theorem, which was shorter than the one in the textbook and I believe to be new. After many attempts, I gave up reminding the student to write it up.

Comment: Write it up yourself with attribution (and permission to use their name) to the originator, and put it on the web.  Take all responsibility for the mistakes, and give all the credit to the student.  If they don't give permission, say so in the writeup (and leave their name out of it), and make it available for circulation.  Roughly speaking, the student owns the use of their own name, and deserves credit for coming up with the proof, but the proof if it is worth reading should belong to everybody.  Gerhard "Mathematics For Using, Not Owning" Paseman, 2016.08.22.

Comment: Specifically, something like the following should keep you out of trouble:  "What follows is my interpretation of an idea from a student, which idea gives a nice proof of result X.  I take full responsibility for any errors, and recommend anyone who uses this interpretation cites it with the following name:YYY."  Here YYY can be "student of domotorp", if that is agreeable instead of using the real name.  People don't have to use YYY, but they should use something that allows others to find your writeup and YYY.  Gerhard "YYY Is Not Your Name" Paseman, 2016.08.22.

Comment: This thread should be moved to "academia", really. As a person who is guilty of "non-publishing" myself (in all three categories), I confirm that Gerhard's suggestion is essentially the only one that will achieve the desired result. Remember, however, that while mathematics cannot be owned, people **can** get offended for a reason and for no reason. So, avoid the "for a reason" category and don't get too surprised with the "for no reason" one when following that advice ;-).

Comment: (3) applies to almost all published results, for the simple reason that most papers don't get read by anyone.

Comment: This situation indeed happens. If you desperately need the result published (for example you want to cite it in your paper), write it yourself and ask the author's permission to publish. There are three variants: a) as his paper, b) as your paper and c) as a joint paper. But there is little you can do without the author's permission.